# Печать документа из QTextDocument

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, print

Возникла необходимость вывести на печать таблицу, заданную html. Вывести нужно на лист формата A4. Ширина колонок таблицы задается в процентном соотношении.

```
QPrinter* pPrinter = new QPrinter(QPrinter::PrinterResolution);
QPrintDialog dlg(pPrinter,this);
if(dlg.exec()){
  QTextDocument doc;
  doc.setHtml(finalReport);
  const QRect pageRect = pPrinter->pageRect();
  doc.setPageSize(pageRect.size());
  QRect contentRect(QPoint(0,0),doc.size().toSize());
  QRect currentRect(0,0,pageRect.width(),pageRect.height());
  QPainter painter(pPrinter);
      while(currentRect.intersects(contentRect)){
      painter.save();
      painter.translate(0,-currentRect.y());
      doc.drawContents(&painter,currentRect);
      painter.restore();

      currentRect.translate(0,currentRect.height());
      if(currentRect.intersects(contentRect)){
          pPrinter->newPage();
        }
    }
}
```

Насколько я понял, после вызова диалога печати `pPrinter` уже должен иметь "правильные" настройки. Однако при печати текст получается уж очень мелкий. Судя по всему, в `QTextDocument` создается огромная страница, которая потом масштабируется  под А4. Собственно, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Как оказалось, метод `QTextDocument::print()` печатает страницу корректно. Глянув исходники `QTextDocument` стало понятно, что `QTextDocumen::drawContents()` просто рисует то, что ему передали в прямоугольнике который ему передали, а  метод `print()` рассчитывает  размер изображения исходя из **dpi**  того paint device, на котором он рисует. Пока ограничился методом `print()`, но буду пробовать учитывать разрешение. Стандартная печать мне не подходит.

Comment: Что на счет WebBrowser или WebContent там есть печать? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15652906/how-to-support-window-print-in-a-embedded-web-browser как вариант

Comment: Похоже решение найдено, и оно довольно простое.